# Open 2 URLs on click from option select

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form there is a drop down list, and on button click I need to open 2 URLs, if user select option 1 then after button click a thank you page appear and another URL should be open.

I am able to open only one URL at current time. Please have a look at my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ty65E/5/

In addition in my page there are few buttons and I want they should initally disabled so they don't worj anymore. and I want to force user to fillup the form first then only he can access the other buttons.

Guys thanks for your Support.

Comment: just normal page, not as a popup

Comment: ok, but how can you open 2 urls in one page ?

Comment: yes atleast one page should open as a lightbox effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is call a onchange function from select option. I think its lot cleaner and will help you later. here is what i tried

```
<select name="interest_c" id="interest_c" class="required" onchange="report(this.value)">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Indicate your interest...</option>
  <option value="1">I want a Free Trial</option>
   <option value="2">I want to see a pre-recorded  demo</option>

                                </select>​



<script type="text/javascript">
function report(selectval) {
    switch(parseInt(selectval))  {

        case 1:
            window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            window.open("http://www.google.com");
            break;   
        case 2:
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com");
        window.open("http://www.php.net");
        break;

    } 

}​
</script>
```

i tried it on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/eXSND/](http://jsfiddle.net/eXSND/1/)

hope this helps

Comment: thank sibu, but if I want to open atleast one URL in a lightbox at parent page, then...any solution?

Comment: @KheemaPandey i doubt it will work in lightbox , maybe you should do google search and if you have doubt post here as another question

Answer (score 1):

You could store more than one URL separating them with something like `'|'`, then use [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to create a list of URLs. The first value will always exist (if you have only one url, split will produce an array with a single element) and the second one will only exist for the option(s) where you specified two URLs.

```
<option value="google.com|stackoverflow.com">Two URLs</option>

val = val.split('|');
window.open(val[0]);
if ( val.length > 1 )
    window.open(val[1]);
```

As for your other question, add the `disabled` property on your buttons, and to each input that must be filled:

```
$(selector_with_all_fields).change(function() {
    var allFilled = true;
    $(selector_with_all_fields).each(function() { 
        allFilled = allFilled && $(this).val() !== "";
    });
    $(my_buttons).attr("disabled",allFilled); // If that doesn't work, try removeAttr when allFilled is false
});
```

Remember to start them with `"disabled"="true"` in the HTML.

Comment: can you provide me a example?

Comment: `window.open` dont have an overload with the second parameter as `_blank`

Comment: @naveen are you sure about that? I've seen many references saying it does (I wasn't able to confirm them though). Anyway, it doesn't matter, since `window.open` will always open a new window. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks guys that work but if I want to open the second URL as a lightbox, is that possible?

Comment: @mgibsonbr: yes i am pretty sure.[`window.open` - Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). `_blank` is used for the `target` attribute of `a` tag.

Comment: @naveen from the docs you posted, it seems that the second argument (called `strWindowName` there) performs the same function as `target`. I mean, if you do `window.open(url,"foo")` and some other page has `<a href=url2 target="foo">` the second url will be opened in the same window. Passing `_blank` as that paramenter is unnecessary, though...

Comment: okay But if I want to open a one URL in a lightbox on parent page, then you have any idea??

Comment: @KheemaPandey sorry, I don't even know what a lightbox is (is this a js library?), I'd suggest searching for and/or asking another question, more to the point.

Comment: click on any image,, this is a lightbox effect

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/